# Ruby Convert string into undescore, avoid the "/" in the resulting string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a name spaced class..

```
"CommonCar::RedTrunk"
```

I need to convert it to an underscored string `"common_car_red_trunk"`, but when I use

`"CommonCar::RedTrunk".underscore`, I get `"common_car/red_trunk"` instead.

Is there another method to accomplish what I need?

Comment: Not being a member of the Rails fraternity I would have thought `to_snake_case` would have been a more descriptive name than `underscore`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland amen, brother. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solutions:

```
"CommonCar::RedTrunk".gsub(':', '').underscore
```

or:

```
"CommonCar::RedTrunk".sub('::', '').underscore
```

or:

```
"CommonCar::RedTrunk".tr(':', '').underscore
```

#### Alternate:

Or turn any of these around and do the `underscore()` first, followed by whatever method you want to use to replace "/" with "_".

## Explanation:

While all of these methods look basically the same, there are subtle differences that can be very impactful.

In short:

- `gsub()` – uses a regex to do pattern matching, therefore, it's finding any occurrence of `":"` and replacing it with `""`.
- `sub()` – uses a regex to do pattern matching, similarly to `gsub()`, with the exception that it's only finding the first occurrence (the "g" in `gsub()` meaning "global"). This is why when using that method, it was necessary to use `"::"`, otherwise a single `":"` would have been left. Keep in mind with this method, it will only work with a single-nested namespace. Meaning `"CommonCar::RedTrunk::BigWheels"` would have been transformed to `"CommonCarRedTrunk::BigWheels"`.
- `tr()` – uses the string parameters as arrays of single character replacments. In this case, because we're only replacing a single character, it'll work identically to `gsub()`. However, if you wanted to replace "on" with "EX", for example, `gsub("on", "EX")` would produce `"CommEXCar::RedTrunk"` while `tr("on", "EX")` would produce `"CEmmEXCar::RedTruXk"`.

## Docs:

https://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub

https://apidock.com/ruby/String/sub

https://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure-Ruby solution.

```
r = /(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|::/
```

```
"CommonCar::RedTrunk".gsub(r, '_').downcase
  #=> "common_car_red_trunk"
```

See (the first form of) [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) and [String#downcase](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-downcase).

The regular expression can be made self-documenting by writing it in *free-spacing mode*:

```
r = /
    (?<=[a-z]) # assert that the previous character is lower-case
    (?=[A-Z])  # assert that the following character is upper-case
    |          # or
    ::         # match '::'
    /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

`(?<=[a-z])` is a *positive lookbehind*; `(?=[A-Z])` is a *positive lookahead*.

Note that `/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/` matches an empty ("zero-width") string. `r` matches, for example, the empty string between `'Common'` and `'Car'`, because it is preceeded by a lower-case letter and followed by an upper-case letter.

I don't know Rails but I'm guessing you could write

```
"CommonCar::RedTrunk".delete(':').underscore
```